# Need to optimize VBA code to run it faster

Tags: vba, performance, optimization

I try to write the VBA to solve my daily work. However, it took me around 2 minute to run this code every time (there are more than 5K data). Here is my VBA code.

```
Sub FindEarliestDate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set gacSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GAC")
Set nopSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("nop")
Set EFTDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("nop").Columns("BZ")

gacLastRow = gacSheet.Cells(gacSheet.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
nopLastRow = nopSheet.Cells(nopSheet.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row


(for earliestDate)
For i = 3 To nopLastRow
nopProd = nopSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value
nopFTY = nopSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value
nopEFTDate = nopSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
foundMatch = False

    For j = 3 To gacLastRow
        gacProd = gacSheet.Cells(j, 6).Value
        gacFTY = gacSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value
        gacBuyDate = gacSheet.Cells(j, 5).Value
        
        If gacProd = nopProd And gacFTY = nopFTY And nopEFTDate = earliestDate And gacBuyDate >= earliestDate Then
            gacDate1 = gacSheet.Cells(j, 12).Value
            
            If Not foundMatch Or gacDate1 < nopDate Then
                nopSheet.Cells(i, "BA").Value = gacDate1
                nopDate = gacDate1
                foundMatch = True
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring you data into an array, instead of working with the cells.

```
' example of setting array to range values
Dim Arr() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
Arr = Range("A1:C5")' Arr is now an allocated array
```

Transfer your data into an output array.  Once all your data is in place, put the array data into the worksheet with one command.

```
'set range values to an array
range.value = array
```

Working with data in an array is significantly faster than working with cells.  In the past, we have seen this technique take some algorithms from minutes to seconds.

In addition to the above, you may want to consider turning calculation off at the beginning and back on at the end; much like you do with screen updating.  This could be impacting your workbook, if changing those cells is triggering Excel to do a recalculation on any linked cells.  However, be sure to have an error trap to turn calculation back to its baseline, if the procedure fails.